# Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new in ASP.NET and I am trying to decorate an action method to allow an administrator to create new user by inserting the first, last names and the balance. The action method should generates Id, account number and AppUserId in the checkingaccount table. However, the post Create action throws the following exception because I am not passing AppUserId

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See
>   'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Is there away I can make the AppuserId added on the table?

Create Action Method

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(string FName, string LName, string UserId, decimal balance)
        {

                var accountNumber = (12 + db.checkAccounts.Count()).ToString().PadLeft(10, '0');
                var checking = new CheckingAccount
                {
                    FirstName = FName,
                    LastName = LName,
                    AccountNumber = accountNumber,
                    Balance = balance,
                    AppUserId = UserId
                };
                db.checkAccounts.Add(checking);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("ViewAccounts");

        }
```

CheckingAccount Model

```
public class CheckingAccount
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Telephone { get; set; }


        public decimal Balance { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "User ID: ")]
        [Required]
        public string AppUserId { get; set; }

    }
```

CheckingAccount Model

```
@model Project.Models.CheckingAccount

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Checking Account</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AccountNumber)
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Balance, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Balance, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Balance, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

         @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
         @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AppUserId)


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
     @Html.ActionLink("Back", "ViewAccounts", null, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Do you have a primary key setup on your model?  Is it set to autoincrement?  Meaning, on insert, an ID is automatically assigned.  I would wager the Id property is the one failing based on your examples.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET, but with Entity Framework. Check the inner details of your exception, and it will tell you exactly what property doesn't match up with the structure of your database.

Comment: Yes, It sets on auto increment

Comment: it shows null for names, AppUserId too!!

Comment: Those last two comments clued me into where your code looks to be incorrect.  Please view my updated answer below (not sure if you get notified of an edit)

Answer (score 2):

Your ActionMethod parameters much match exactly the names of the form fields.  You are using `FName` and `LName` for instance when your actual model properties are `FirstName` and `LastName`.  As a result, your parameters are empty strings.  The model binder has no idea that `FName` and `FirstName` are supposed to be the same thing for instance.

Either correct your parameter names in your action method:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Create(string FirstName, string LastName, string AppUserId, decimal Balance){
```

**OR**

Since you are using strongly typed views, just use the model from your View as your Create ActionResult parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CheckingAccount model){
    //fancy black magic binds all of the form properties 
    //to this model parameter for you!
    model.AccountNumber = (12 + db.checkAccounts.Count()).ToString().PadLeft(10, '0');
    db.checkAccounts.Add(model);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Additionally, you can use the following code to get the specific entity errors:

```
try{
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException e){
    foreach (var error in e.EntityValidationErrors){
        foreach (var propertyError in error.ValidationErrors){
            Console.WriteLine($"{propertyError.PropertyName} had the following issue: {propertyError.ErrorMessage}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but the updates didn't go through and had the same issue!

Comment: What are the errors that are coming back?  Are you sure your data is getting bound to the model?  Set a breakpoint at the db.SaveChanges() line, hover over the model variable and see what data is inside of it

Comment: Its the AppUser comes will " " value

Comment: When you are GETing the create page....are you sending it an AppUserId in the model?  If its null on the page, it will be null when it gets POSTed back to your method.

Comment: I think I get it as a null but I wanted to post it to a values into the checkingAccount table!

Comment: I have created similar method in my Account controller when the user first register the AppUserId adds up automatically!but It doesn't work on the create !

Comment: @Dodi82 - Then somewhere along the way, the method in the Account controller is setting the AppUserId on that model.  If you do not set that (or any other property), then it will be NULL.  If the DB is configured to not allow NULL value into the column, then you get the error you are getting (DbValidationException).  We have identified the issue, its up to you to figure out the difference between the Account method and this method.

Comment: I understand what you said Tommy. I have created very similar approach and it worked by returning a value once a new user register. The AppUserId is created in the table by adding a string value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130311/discussion-between-dodi82-and-tommy).

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your offending code with a try catch, with the in the catch to see the specific Entity Framework errors that you need to resolve. If you dont know what to do once you have the detailed errors post back here. But more information would be helpful.

```
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    // Retrieve the error messages as a list of strings.
    var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
            .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
            .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

    // Join the list to a single string.
    var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

    // Combine the original exception message with the new one.
    var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

    // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
    throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
}
```

Comment: It was on try catch but had to disable it to find out the error's location

Comment: Sure, but this will help you get all the errors that are happening here, now that you know where it is.

Comment: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details. The validation errors are: The First Name:  field is required.; The Last Name:  field is required.; The User ID:  field is required. Even though I pass the names in each text box